# INNER JOIN but not editing rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set the *adminid* of **CTBan_Log** to the value of **sb_admins** *aid* (admin id) but only where the *steamid* matches the *authid* of the row

```
UPDATE CTBan_Log ct 
    INNER JOIN sb_admins s ON
               ct.adminid = s.aid
    INNER JOIN sb_admins st ON 
               ct.admin_steamid = st.authid
SET adminid=s.aid WHERE admin_steamid=st.authid
```

this executes but doesn't edit any rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As Gordon said in the answer, well not that he said it, but it does not appear that you need an alias of a self-join because you have no criteria or OP description of why you need such of a thing.

Comment: The referenced dupe close may bring in more tables but it is a canonical reference. Use accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't really look like it should ever actually change anything. Specifically, the first join condition insures the SET will be effectively a "no op".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description suggests this logic:

```
UPDATE CTBan_Log ct INNER JOIN
       sb_admins s 
       ON ct.adminid = s.aid AND
          ct.admin_steamid = st.authid
    SET ct.adminid = s.aid ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't edit any rows

Comment: @Joram . . . Then either the `join` conditions don't match any rows or the `adminid` doesn't actually change value.